# How to change uppercase to lowercase in a string?

Tags: python, string, uppercase, lowercase

The overall goal of this program is to count the occurrences of a word that the user inputs. To do this I need all of the words in this long string to be lowercase. I do not want to print the entire string with

```
print s.lower()
```

I just want this to actually change the string to lowercase without printing it out.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question; it can be confusing when you don't know the difference between mutable and immutable objects.

Comment: Perfect! For some reason using s = s.lower() wasn't working a few minutes ago, but it's fixed now!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what language this is, but presumably, you have to do this:

```
s = s.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it to a new string.

```
lower = s.lower()
```